# How to use the METHOD_OPT parameter in DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle-11g, plsql

Hi there I was just wondering what would be the difference between these 2 METHOD_OPT parameter settings:

```
FOR COLUMNS SIZE 5 some_column
```

and

```
FOR COLUMNS some_column SIZE 5
```

both will create a histogram with 5 buckets for the column 'some_column' right?

The official Oracle reference states that METHOD_OPT should have this form:

> FOR COLUMNS [size clause] column|attribute [size_clause]
>   [,column|attribute [size_clause]...]

but this doesn't really help my case.

I've seen sources which use both versions so not sure if there is any difference.

EDIT

I was told that both of these are the exact same, but then what about these 2:

```
FOR COLUMNS SIZE 5 some_column SIZE 6 some_column2
```

and

```
FOR COLUMNS some_column SIZE 5 some_column2 SIZE 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the syntax I would expect that `COLUMS size_clause` is a global setting, that can be overridden by specific `size_clause` for a single column. So in case of `FOR COLUMNS SIZE 5 col1 SIZE 6, col2` means `SIZE 6` takes precedence for col1, but col2 falls back to the default `SIZE 5`. This is what I would certainly expect, but I haven't verified this experimentally.